# How can I set buffer-local value for a variable defined by defcustom?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In emacs, we can define customizable user option variable.

> defcustom - Programming in Emacs Lisp http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/defcustom.html

And we can make variable to have buffer-local binding.

> Creating Buffer-Local - GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Buffer_002dLocal.html#Creating-Buffer_002dLocal

If I want to make non-customizable variable, I can use `make-local-variable` or `setq-local`.

But I can't find any ways how to make customizable variable to have buffer-local binding.

Even if I call `make-local-variable` for variable defined by `defcustom`, `custom-set-variables` set to **global-value**.

If I call `setq-local`, value is set to local-variable. It is better. But I don't think this is best practice.

Is there any valid ways how to set buffer-local value for a variable defined by defcustom?

Comment: To set (in code) a buffer-local variable for *any* variable, use `setq-local` (or `make-local-variable` prior to Emacs 24.3). That *is* best-practice. Is your question actually "How can I specify *within* a `defcustom` declaration that a variable should always be buffer-local?" ? Or perhaps "How can I use the Customize user-interface to set a buffer-local value for a variable?" ?

Comment: @phils Sorry about my language ability. I wanted to ask is that "Is there a function like be compounded `setq-local` and `custom-set-variables`?". But @Drew posted comprehensive answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is: You can't, at least not using the Customize UI.

What you can do is add a sexp that sets the buffer-local value of the variable to your init file.

Do ***one*** of the following:

- Make it *always* buffer-local, no matter what the buffer is:

  `(make-variable-buffer-local 'the-variable)`

  You can put this anywher in your init file.
- Make it buffer-local only for the current buffer, i.e., for some buffer after you select it:

  `(make-local-variable 'the-variable)`

  For that, you need to put the sexp in a sexp that selects the buffer you want.  That could be, for example:

  `(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "the-buffer-name")
     (make-local-variable 'the-variable))`

  That assumes that the buffer can be reasonably created or already exists.  If you do this, do it **after** your `custom-file` has been loaded.  That is, in your init file, either after loading `custom-file` (which I recommend) or, if you do not use `custom-file`, after any code generated automatically by Customize (e.g., `custom-set-variables`).

  You can alternatively put the `make-local-variable` sexp on a mode hook, so whenever you are in a buffer that has a particular mode, it is executed.

All of that said, I submitted an [***enhancement request***](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=12949) to Emacs Dev in 2012, requesting that user's be able to *use the Customize UI to set* (and possibly save) *buffer-local values of user options*. It sleeps in category "wishlist", so far.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I don't want to use `setq` for the customizable user option variables. I have no choise but to use `setq` . I hope your request will be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

After defcustom form write

```
(make-variable-buffer-local 'my-var)
```

Now, if you change the value in some buffer, other buffers will keep resp. deliver the old customized one.

Comment: I know this can be work when I use `setq`. But I wanted to ask about when use `custom-set-variables`. Sorry and Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Customize is mostly designed for persistent configuration, i.e. configuration that is saved in the config file so it also applies to future Emacs sessions.  But buffers are not persistent: when you restart Emacs you get a new buffer object.
So persistent customization "per-buffer" is not a clearly defined concept.  We could/should add Customize support for settings that are specific to some major modes (i.e. "per-mode" settings), on the other hand.

Comment: Thank you for the your good information. Customize is good when defining user configurable value. But I want to control them by my plugin. I conceived a way call `custom-set-variables` when every time `window-configuration-change-hook` is launched. But I think this is dirty way...